# No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an add-on which requires access to various Google services, and requests the following access when initially loaded:

[image]

I also have a webapp which runs as me (the same google account as the add-on) and can be accessed by anyone including anonymous.  The webapp trys to access a form which I believe I should already have access to.

Webapp:

```
function doGet(){
  var form = FormApp.openById('');
  var formId = form.getId();
  var items = form.getItems();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Form contains "+items.length+"items.");
}
```

Error:

> No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have
>   permission to access it.

**Question:**

When the add-on initially requests access to the user's Drive, does this give access to the *add-on only* or to the *developers google account*?

Comment: Try opening the script and running any function as the user who published the web-app.  Might be an issue with you not having given the script the proper authorizations.  If you have made any changes since you published it you may need to re-authorize, or maybe even re-publish under a new version number.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, the problem was the ID, in order to fix the problem you need to pass the **edit ID of the form**.
I've attached a picture to further describe.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because on the following line:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('');
```

The `openById` parameter is `''`. It will be solved by passing the form ID.

You could get the form ID from the URL or by using [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getid).

Related Q&A

- [Easiest way to get file ID from URL on Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16840038/1595451)

Comment: My thought is that the actual id was removed from the posted code for privacy reasons. But with no response from @beano, no way to know for sure.