# How to retrieve file id from google drive file URL

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have the URL of the file, to get details of the file, file_id is required? Is there any way to retrieve file_id from the URL.I'm looking for something like

```
$driveService->files->getFileIdFromUrl($url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Google doesn't provide an explicit interface, so using a regex to extract the id string is probably your best bet.

See [Easiest way to get file ID from URL on Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840038/easiest-way-to-get-file-id-from-url-on-google-apps-script) for how to do this javascript.

Regexes are available in php.  You can test your php regexes at http://www.phpliveregex.com/