# How to add 'field' property to a Google Drive API v3 call in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-oauth

tl;dr I am new to JavaScript and Google Apps Script and I have no idea how to add the 'fields' property to a Google Drive v3 API call.

I am trying to modify file permissions in a G Suite domain using Google Apps Script, a service account, and [the OAuth 2 sample from Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs). I wrote a function for Drive API v3 to replace Drive API v2 `getIdForEmail`, but API v3 requires the 'fields' query parameter to request specific fields.

The error given when I run the script is:

> Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about returned code 400. Truncated server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "The 'fields' parameter is required for this meth...

I found the answer in a different programming language but can't translate it to Google Apps Script / JavaScript. See **Fields** on the previous answer: [Google Drive API v3 Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration/35143284#35143284). How do I add the 'fields' property to request 'permissionId'?

```
    function getPermissionIdForEmail(userEmail) {
      var service = getService(userEmail);
      if (service.hasAccess()) {
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about';
        var options = {
          'method': 'get',
          'contentType': 'application/json'
        };

        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
          }
        });
        var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        Logger.log('getPermissionIdForEmail result: %s', JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
      } else {
        Logger.log('getPermissionIdForEmail getLastError: %s', service.getLastError());
      }
     }
```

---

Edit: Thank you Cameron Roberts for the help. The solution I used is

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about' + '?fields=user/permissionId';
```

Comment: Additional links I coudn't post due to low rep score: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail, https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration, https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/about/get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recall offhand if Google will accept a POST request here, if they will this could be passed as a request payload:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
  },
  payload: {
     fields: 'kind,user,storageQuota' 
  }
});
```

Or if it must be a GET request you can append the parameters directly to the url:

```
url = url+'?fields=kind,user,storageQuota'
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution in this case is using url = url + '?fields=user/permissionId' with a GET request.