# Send email with attachment 'is not a function error'

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, sendmail, email-attachments

I would like help to resolve the error when executing this function.

**file.next is not a function error**

```
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet_bd = ss.getSheetByName('BD');
var numRows = sheet_bd.getLastRow();
var pdf = sheet_bd.getRange(numRows, 3).getValue();
var file = pdf.slice(33, 66);

//console.log(pdf.slice(33, 66));

     MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: 'email@email.com',   
     subject: "test", 
     body:"Test message",
     attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)],

  });
  
}
```

Comment: what is the result of `var file = pdf.slice(33, 66);` ? Looks like it may be a file in drive info, is that right?

Comment: the result is the id of a file that is on the drive which is in this format https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XwCesyVWp-WpYm8pNFkOiH663rNqHx2b

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet, `file` ultimately comes from [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), which doesn't return an [iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), so you cannot use the [next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#next) method.

If you're getting the link of the file, you need to use it to load the file with [getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid). But to do that, you need to [extract just the ID of the file from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16840612/3751868).

Based on the above, you can modify your snippet to something like this:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_bd = ss.getSheetByName('BD');
  var numRows = sheet_bd.getLastRow();
  var filename = sheet_bd.getRange(numRows, 3).getValue();
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(filename.match(/[-\w]{25,}/))

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: 'email@email.com',
    subject: "test",
    body: "Test message",
    attachments: [pdf.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],

  });

}
```

Comment: I didn't understand perfectly

Could you exemplify?

At the end, I would like to send you a pdf file that is on my drive, which address is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XwCesyVWp-WpYm8pNFkOiH663rNqHx2b

Comment: Sure, I added a sample code to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to attach a file to an email with a Drive file link

You have this string:

```
"drive.google.com/open?id=1XwCesyVWp-WpYm8pNFkOiH663rNqHx2b"
```

All this is right now is a string, not an object or a link. To get the file behind the link you need to use the [Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), to get the file, and then get the [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) of the file. You need the blob because the `sendEmail` method requires this.

```js
let id = file.match(/id=.+/)[0].slice(3) // This extracts the id from the url.
let driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
let blob = driveFile.getBlob()

MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: 'email@email.com',   
     subject: "test", 
     body:"Test message",
     attachments: [blob],
  });
```

#### Reference

- [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
- [getBlob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob())
- [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)
- [sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object))

Comment: tks for answer ... solved using DriveApp.getFileById