# Upload google form files to two different google drive folders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form that has two file upload sections. I want to be able to upload those files to two different folders. The files in the first file upload section should go in Folder one and the files in the second file upload section should go in folder two. I also want to automatically name the folders based on the name of the senders. Folders should go as follow: sendername_1, sendername_2, etc, if the senders have the same name. How would I make this happen? I found the script below but it seems to only work with folder 1. Folder 2 has the files from the second file upload section but it doesn't automatically create a folder for them.

```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {
  

    const folderId = "1y40PNXYXSm7Ue_b6nbVnauz7dzKiKj4u";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination folders.

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
itemResponses[2].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would I make this script work to achieve the goal stated above

Comment: That's too broad.  Focus down to a more unique problem within the script.  Were not here to write free code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of how I would approach it:

```
function getIdFromUrl(url) 
{ 
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); 
}

function automateFile (e) {

var name = e.values[2]
var file1 = e.values[3]; 
var file2 = e.values[4];
var drive = DriveApp;
var parentFolder = drive.getFolderById("1vJcsklbZ_Lk0b3CH0JxUHN8UzNI0eKXV"); //Set Parent Folder ID
var createFolder1 = drive.createFolder(name + '_1').moveTo(parentFolder);
var createFolder2 = drive.createFolder(name + '_2').moveTo(parentFolder);

var getfileId1 = getIdFromUrl(file1); //Gets the file ID 1
  drive.getFileById(getfileId1).moveTo(createFolder1); // Moves the file to Folder1 

var getfileId2 = getIdFromUrl(file2); //Gets the file ID 2
  drive.getFileById(getfileId2).moveTo(createFolder2); // Moves the file to Folder2 

}
```

**NOTES:**
This script was done on Google Sheets Apps Script, which is the created sheet for Form Responses on Google Forms.

Make sure you create a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) like so:
[image]

I used this function `getIdFromUrl(url)` from this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840038/easiest-way-to-get-file-id-from-url-on-google-apps-script) since `file1` and `file2` only returns the whole URL, and not the file ID, and as of now there is no `getFileById` method to move the uploaded files from your form.

**Screenshot of my Google Form:** [image]

**Inside Drive:**
[image]

**Files are moved inside the created folders:**
[image][image]

Comment: Wow, Thank you. That works perfectly!

Comment: No problem! If this answer helped out, I would appreciate it if you click the accept button on the left (check icon) so that other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Just a quick question. Will those folders only be able to contain one file each?