# Bootstrap make menu item active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this url www.url.com/photos that will make the "photos" item on my menu active. However, if I go to the edit page www.url.com/photos/edit, the active item disappears. I have discovered that this is where the active item is being controlled but how do I make it so that it will remain active even in my edit pages?

This is the code I found

```
var url = window.location;
//    console.log(url);
    // var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    //     return this.href == url;
    // }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
    var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).addClass('active').parent();

    while (true) {
        if (element.is('li')) {
            element = element.parent().addClass('in').parent();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

EDIT : I found a solution in the end. Thank you for everyone who helped!

Replace my code with this one

```
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
    }).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
    if (element.is('li')) {
        element.addClass('active');
    }
```

Comment: use a regex for this, this should prove sufficient https://regex101.com/r/iqRw7d/1

Comment: Thanks! But where do I place this regex? in the part before the filter?

Comment: i guess so, give it a try

Answer (score 0):

check below fiddle you can use `.indexof`
and change href variable with this.href in your code

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3g7j9fLL/6/)

Comment: Hey thanks! But this assumes that only photos will be chosen at the time?

Comment: Hey if my url is window.location what will the href be?

Comment: url = window.location.href that is current page url and href is this.href
check updated fiddle

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of using a filter, try using an attribute selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. The approach I'll take will cut off the first url path segment ([Regex to get first word after slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735483/regex-to-get-first-word-after-slash-in-url)) and target the href that contains that word.

```
const active_path = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');

// element is a vague variable name here, what is this element?
// maybe we could rename it to navigation_tab

const element = $(`ul.nav a[href*=${active_path}]`).addClass('active').parent();

// no idea what your while statement was trying to do,
// but passing while(true) will always be true so let's
// rewrite that to just be an if statement. You also don't
// need an else if you're just trying to accomplish one thing.
// This also is very unreadable code, as I have no idea what
// you're trying to accomplish. As you get better, you'll learn
// to create code that can read like a book and tell anyone what
// you're trying to accomplish. I would also encourage you to
// learn how to do these things without relying on jQuery. good luck!

if (element.is('li')) {
  element = element.parent().addClass('in').parent();
}
```

**Revision**

I wonder if you're not really understanding how the .parent() works. If you're trying to add the class to the parent element, then you need to have parent() before. But I would separate those concerns by defining the element first and then adding your class later.

```
const active_path = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
const active_tab = $(`ul.nav li a[href*=${active_path}]`).parent();
active_tab.addClass('active');
```

https://codepen.io/jaruesink/pen/PmzKjo?editors=1111 (see comments for more details)

If this doesn't work for you then double check to see if you can use ES6 syntax. I would recommend developing in Chrome/Safari or figuring out how to use Babel. Or if you still can't use ES6 syntax, then you need to change the const to vars and $(`ul.nav li a[href*=${active_path}]`) to $('ul.nav li a[href*='+active_path+']')

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, I tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hmm. After I wake up, I'll see if I can put into a codepen and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var storedListItem = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedListItem');
$("ul.nav > li > a:eq("+(storedListItem)+")").addClass("active");
$("ul.nav > li").on("click",function(){
    var index = $(this).index('ul.nav > li');
    var selectedListItem = index;
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedListItem', JSON.stringify(selectedListItem));
});
```

this sets the click list item in an unordered list to the active menu item.